# If statement on array

Tags: java, primitive-types, comparison-operators

I have the following java bit

```
if(board[i][col].equals(true))
    return false
```

However, when I compile it I get the following error - "int cannot be dereferenced" - can anybody please explan what this means?

Thanks!

Comment: Show us the declaration of `board[i][col]`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402008/int-cannot-be-dereferenced

Answer (score 8):

It is probably an array of primitive types (`int`?).

Use `==`, it'll be fine. But if it's `int`, make sure you're not comparing it to `true`: Java is strong typed.

You use `equals` when you want to test for equality two distinct objects.

Comment: Indeed, I think that may very well be the case... Sorry, I'm new to Java and used to less strict languages :) Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hm ok this, is weird, the array is declared as:

    boolean[][] chessboard;
    chessboard = new boolean[rows][cols];

And retrieved as: 

    boolean[][] board = initiate.getChessboard();

But I still get the same error...

Answer (score 4):

```java
    // Assuming
    int[][] board = new int[ROWS][COLS];

    // In other languages, such as C and C++, an integer != 0 evaluates to true
    // if(board[i][col]) //this wont work, because Java is strongly typed.

    // You'd need to do an explicit comparison, which evaluates to a boolean
    // for the same behavior.
    // Primitives don't have methods and need none for direct comparison:
    if (board[i][col] != 0)
        return false;

    // If you expect the value of true to be 1:
    if (board[i][col] == 1)
        return false;

    // Assuming
    boolean[][] board = new boolean[ROWS][COLS];

    if (board[i][col] == true)
        return false;

    // short:
    if (board[i][col])
        return false;

    // in contrast
    if (board[i][col] == false)
        return false;

    // should be done using the logical complement operator (NOT)
    if (!board[i][col])
        return false;
```

Comment: `if(board[i][col] == true)` ==> `if(board[i][col])` is more standard and readable.

Comment: It's about the comparison, but that is indeed how one should do that. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

With the following declaration:

```
boolean[][] board = initiate.getChessboard();
```

You need to use the following condition:

```
if(board[i][col] == true)
    return false;
```

Which could also be written:

```
if(board[i][col])
    return false;
```

This is because `equals` only applies to objects and boolean is not an object, it is a primitive type.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(board[i][col])
    return false
```

If the array as `boolean[][]` comparison is made with `==`. And comparing `== true` can also be left out.

Answer (score 0):

If `board` is an array of `boolean` primitives, use

```
if(board[i][col] == true)
  return false;
```

or

```
if (board[i][col]) return false;
```

or

```
return !board[i][col];
```